# Will Rapberry Pi overload?

Tags: raspberry-pi, load-balancing, raspbian

[Nodes map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R028e.jpg)

Let's begin from the worker servers: As it's shown in the pic, I have two

> Raspberry's with  512GB ram working on 700Mhz

as servers storing my website. All of source code, images, icon files and others are storaed by them. As an extra, 1st rasPi has a wifi dongle plugged on it. these two also hawe scripts on them, which do following jobs: when I scp web sites updated version in .tar.gz format, it extract's it and sync with the second one. However, my concerns are about the load balancer. Load balancer stores database that website will be using all the time and Hard disk drive(cloud storage that user will be reaching via veb site as well). As I mentioned, this raspi also possesses the job of load balancing. Will it overload due to this much task? If it will, is there a solution for that? Thanks in advance! All answers will be appreciated...

Comment: This is a hardware question. You might want to move it to the appropriate Stack. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Ctrl-C Ctrl-V ?